# change the button color of mat-spinner-button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a button spinner control on my page. It only comes with three colors: primary, accent, warn. I want a background button color that is the current color of my web page. I tried to change the color by using the stylesheet in styles.scss, but the color did not get changed

```
.spinner-button {
background-color: currentColor;

}
```

Below is the code in my HTML file:

```
 <mat-spinner-button  [options]="spinnerButtonOptions" (btnClick)="LoadData()" class="spinner-button" >
</mat-spinner-button>
```

Below are the options in my .ts class:

```
spinnerButtonOptions: MatProgressButtonOptions = {
    active: false,
    text: 'Load Data',
    spinnerSize: 18,
    raised: true,
    stroked: false,
    fullWidth: false,
    disabled: false,
    mode: 'indeterminate',
    buttonIcon: {
      fontIcon: '3d_rotation'
    }
  }
```

Below is the image :

[image]

I want the button color of Load Data to be green, #5B5B39; similar to other two button: "Start Loading" and "FTP"

Comment: Could you provide the HTML template of your custom `mat-spinner-button`, and also the typescript metadata and CSS?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for and how to achieve it. My HTML and typescript and HTML are pasted above.

Comment: is `mat-spinner-button` is a custom component created by you?

Comment: I think @prashant-pimpale got what I was asking for and already answered that. You should add the information saying you are using a library `called mat-progress-buttons`. This is an important piece of information to get your question solved faster. See @prashant-pimpale's answer below.

Comment: Hey, I am the plugin author, @PrashantPimpale was kind enough to create a PR [describing](https://github.com/michaeldoye/mat-progress-buttons#overriding-default-css) how to override the default styling. If this does not work for you, let me know and I can find an alternative way to do this via the package itself. (if it does work, please accept his answer :) )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override CSS and set ViewEncapsulation to None:

Component.css:

```
.mat-raised-button.mat-primary {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Component.ts:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { MatProgressButtonOptions } from 'mat-progress-buttons'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation : ViewEncapsulation.None // Here
})
```

Here is the working [`demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-progress-buttons-demo-frz3ue):)